# Does Kafka broker do zero-copy writes to Page cache/disk when it gets messages from producer? if so, how does it do any sanity checks?

Tags: apache-kafka

I read everywhere that Kafka does zero-copy reads when a consumer polls for messages but I am trying to understand if zero-copy happens during writes by the producer(so ignore consumer side).

I see that `Filechannel.transferTo` would do zero-copy but that is simply piping the stream but how about if broker need to do some checks before flushing the data? like say, if length of the buffer > m then flush otherwise hold in the buffer or say some other sanity checks or some other application logic that involves the buffer. And for this to happen the buffer needs to be accessible in the user space(assuming no mmap is used by Kafka for this purpose)? if so, then kernel buffers need to be copied over to user space? essentially no zero-copy on the write side.

Comment: Are you talking about client- or broker side of the pipeline?

Comment: broker side (after receiving the data from the client/producer)